# WCF Duplex communication with InterSystems

Tags: wcf, intersystems-cache, wcf-4

Can someone point me to a sample of how to call a WCF service using wsDualHttpBinding?  I created the classes using the SOAP Client Wizard and everything compiles.  When I run the objectscript code, it hangs on the web service call for a while (it's hitting a timeout) and returns an exception:

> |      oref value: 4
>    |      class name: %Exception.SystemException
>    |             OID: ""
>    | reference count: 2 (system)
>    +----------------- attribute values ------------------
>    |               Code = 64
>    |               Data = ""
>    |     InnerException = ""
>    |     Location = "zInvokeClient+349^Service.WSDualHttpBindingIService.1"
>    |     Name = ""

and %objlasterror gives:

```
0 3"%zRead+31^%Net.HttpRequest.1:SAMPLES
```

LOCATION is set to `"http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/PNServices/Service1/"`

Any idea/clues?

Comment: what version your cache server
$zv

Comment: @DAiMor - Cache for Windows (x86-64) 2009.1.2 (Build 602U)

Comment: I not found %zRead method in %Net.HttpRequest class, but I found Read, and in code error "Timed out waiting for response from server".  Are you sure, what server is available?

Comment: Yes, server is available and working.  I have one wcf service that uses normal http bindings and is just like SOAP web service, it works fine, duplicated it but with different bindings and I can call it from every place except intersystems :(

Comment: can you put generated code SOAP client and original WSDL. Maybe Cache' misunderstood server's WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight advice: Try using `w ##class(%SYSTEM.Status).GetErrorText(status)` where status is for example %objlasterror or sc. It is somewhat human readable unlike the status itself.